# Do half-elves have the Elven Accuracy power?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

In the DDI character builder, when building a half-elf character you can select the *Elven Arcane Precision* feat. This is an enhancement of the *Elven Accuracy* racial power. But the resulting character sheet does not feature *Elven Accuracy* itself as a power.

Where is the error? Do half-elves have the *Elven Accuracy* power (ie. the error is in omitting it from the character sheet)? Or do they not (ie. the error is in allowing the selection of *Elven Arcane Precision* in the first place)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Half-elves don't have Elven Accuracy. They do, however, have access to all the elven racial feats. Elven Arcane Precision won't do anything for them, but they can, technically, take it.

Comment: So while it's not technically an error, it *is* still useless to take it (although I think it would make sense to have *Elven Accuracy* be an explicit prerequisite for *Elven Arcane Precision*). I presume there's no other way for a half-elf character to otherwise obtain *Elven Accuracy*?

Comment: 4e tries to avoid prerequisites whenever it can, beyond simple race or class and occasional stat. Most of the time, the prerequisite of a race would be enough to guarantee the racial power. My DDI subscription has long since lapsed, so I'll say there's *likely* no other way to get Elven Accuracy. There could be a paragon path that embraces its innate elfishness, or something like that.

Comment: @Magician Compendium comes with 0 Paragon Path or Epic Destiny results for a search of _elven accuracy_.

Comment: There's an epic destiny or two that let you count as more races and acquire their racial powers. I believe one for devas and one for primal characters.